# invalid integer error, I am not sure what that means

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, axios, stripe-payments

I am following some tutorials to implement stripe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DF68MNDxVwU&t=12211s and https://alterclass.io/tutorials/create-an-ecommerce-website-with-nextjs-and-stripe
Unfortunately they are both done before stripe updated their docs.
I am following along with these and looking at the docs at the same time to try and get it to work but I have been debugging this for like 20 hours now with no luck.

2 questions:

1. could someone help me pin point what I am doing wrong?
2. all of the tutorials I have found, NOT on the stripe docs page, have used a function to send items in the cart to the backend. The walkthrough on the stripe page doesn't show this function. Does anyone know where this function is in the stripe docs?

I have tried doing exactly as the stripe walkthrough showed and it at least would link me to another page, but I couldn't figure out how to send the items in my cart with it. I would be redirected to a blank screen

here is the error I am getting:
error - StripeInvalidRequestError: Invalid integer: NaN
at StripeError.generate (/Users/cameron/nextjs-amazon-clone/node_modules/stripe/lib/Error.js:38:16)
at res.toJSON.then.StripeAPIError.message (/Users/cameronautism/nextjs-amazon-clone/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:190:35)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
type: 'StripeInvalidRequestError',
raw: {
code: 'parameter_invalid_integer',
doc_url: 'https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-invalid-integer',
message: 'Invalid integer: NaN',
param: 'line_items[0][price_data][unit_amount]',
request_log_url: 'https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_DZ6nOqke9AHTHi?t=1670342108',
type: 'invalid_request_error',
headers: {
server: 'nginx',
date: 'Tue, 06 Dec 2022 15:55:08 GMT',
'content-type': 'application/json',
'content-length': '369',
connection: 'keep-alive',
'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE',
'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
'access-control-max-age': '300',
'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
'idempotency-key': 'e9fdd45b-a707-4421-adfb-e327b7bef077',
'original-request': 'req_DZ6nOqke9AHTHi',
'request-id': 'req_DZ6nOqke9AHTHi',
'stripe-version': '2022-11-15',
'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload'
},
statusCode: 400,
requestId: 'req_DZ6nOqke9AHTHi'
},
rawType: 'invalid_request_error',
code: 'parameter_invalid_integer',
doc_url: 'https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-invalid-integer',
param: 'line_items[0][price_data][unit_amount]',
detail: undefined,
headers: {
server: 'nginx',
date: 'Tue, 06 Dec 2022 15:55:08 GMT',
'content-type': 'application/json',
'content-length': '369',
connection: 'keep-alive',
'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE',
'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
'access-control-max-age': '300',
'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
'idempotency-key': 'e9fdd45b-a707-4421-adfb-e327b7bef077',
'original-request': 'req_DZ6nOqke9AHTHi',
'request-id': 'req_DZ6nOqke9AHTHi',
'stripe-version': '2022-11-15',
'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload'
},
requestId: 'req_DZ6nOqke9AHTHi',
statusCode: 400,
charge: undefined,
decline_code: undefined,
payment_intent: undefined,
payment_method: undefined,
payment_method_type: undefined,
setup_intent: undefined,
source: undefined,
page: '/api/checkout_sessions'
}
wait  - compiling /...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 684 ms (909 modules)
error - StripeInvalidRequestError: Invalid integer: NaN
at StripeError.generate (/Users/cameronautism/nextjs-amazon-clone/node_modules/stripe/lib/Error.js:38:16)
at res.toJSON.then.StripeAPIError.message (/Users/cameronautism/nextjs-amazon-clone/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:190:35)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
type: 'StripeInvalidRequestError',
raw: {
code: 'parameter_invalid_integer',
doc_url: 'https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-invalid-integer',
message: 'Invalid integer: NaN',
param: 'line_items[0][price_data][unit_amount]',
request_log_url: 'https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_p7bQKyDNDYJcw3?t=1670342119',
type: 'invalid_request_error',
headers: {
server: 'nginx',
date: 'Tue, 06 Dec 2022 15:55:19 GMT',
'content-type': 'application/json',
'content-length': '369',
connection: 'keep-alive',
'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE',
'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
'access-control-max-age': '300',
'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
'idempotency-key': 'f982b912-71b7-4583-b1c4-1918d03b8968',
'original-request': 'req_p7bQKyDNDYJcw3',
'request-id': 'req_p7bQKyDNDYJcw3',
'stripe-version': '2022-11-15',
'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload'
},
statusCode: 400,
requestId: 'req_p7bQKyDNDYJcw3'
},
rawType: 'invalid_request_error',
code: 'parameter_invalid_integer',
doc_url: 'https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-invalid-integer',
param: 'line_items[0][price_data][unit_amount]',
detail: undefined,
headers: {
server: 'nginx',
date: 'Tue, 06 Dec 2022 15:55:19 GMT',
'content-type': 'application/json',
'content-length': '369',
connection: 'keep-alive',
'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE',
'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
'access-control-max-age': '300',
'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
'idempotency-key': 'f982b912-71b7-4583-b1c4-1918d03b8968',
'original-request': 'req_p7bQKyDNDYJcw3',
'request-id': 'req_p7bQKyDNDYJcw3',
'stripe-version': '2022-11-15',
'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload'
},
requestId: 'req_p7bQKyDNDYJcw3',
statusCode: 400,
charge: undefined,
decline_code: undefined,
payment_intent: undefined,
payment_method: undefined,
payment_method_type: undefined,
setup_intent: undefined,
source: undefined,
page: '/api/checkout_sessions'
}

here is my backend code

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { items, email } = req.body;

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    shipping_rates: ["shr_1MBn0HFqoomU2P4qZk4vqOQ3"],
    shipping_address_collection: {
      allowed_countries: ["US", "CA", "GB"],
    },
  line_items:[   { quantity: 1,
    price_data: { 
      currency: 'usd',
      unit_amount: items.price * 100,
      product_data: {  
        description: items.description,
        name: items.title,
      }}}],
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: `${process.env.HOST}/success`,
    cancel_url: `${process.env.HOST}/checkout`,
    metadata: {
      email,
      images: JSON.stringify(items.map(items => items.image))
    }
  });
  res.status(200).JSON({ id:session.id});
};
```

here is my front end:

button that is using the function is at the bottom

```
import Header from "../public/components/Header";
import Image from "next/image";
import CheckoutProduct from "../public/components/CheckoutProduct";

import React, { useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { useAppContext } from "../public/state";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import axios from 'axios';
// import CheckoutForm from "../public/components/CheckoutForm";
const stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.stripe_public_key);


function Checkout() {
  const [basket, addToBasket] = useAppContext();
  const { data: session } = useSession();



  const itemsInBasketEqualToProducts = basket.map(item => item.price);
 
  const sum = itemsInBasketEqualToProducts.reduce(
    (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue,
    0
  );
  
  const createCheckoutForm = async () => {
    const stripe = await stripePromise;

    //call the backend to create a checkout session...
    const checkoutSession = await axios.post('/api/checkout_sessions', 
    {
      items: basket,
      email: session.user.email
    }) 
    const result = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    sessionId: checkoutSession.data.id
  });

  if (result.error) {
    alert(result.error.message)
  };
  };


  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-100">
      <Header />
     
       <main className="lg:flex max-w-screen-xl mx-auto">
        {/* this is to test if the array of objects are being assigned correctly , this is also the proper way to satisfy react if you get the error objects are not valid as a react child*/}
          {/* <div>
            {basketItemsObject.map((item) => (
              <p>{item.id}</p>
            ))}
          
          </div> */}

        
        {/* left*/}
        <div className="flex-grow m-5 shadow-lg">
          <Image 
          src="https://links.papareact.com/ikj"
          width={2000}
          height={250}
          objectfit='contain'
          />

          <div className="flex flex-col p-5 space-y-5 bg-white">
            <h1 className="text-3xl border-b pb-4">
              {/* {maybe} */}
              {basket.length === 0 ? 'Your Basket is empty' : 'Shopping Basket'}
              </h1>
              <CheckoutProduct/>
          </div>
        </div>

        {/* right */}
            {/* subtotal */}
            <div className=" bg-white  shadow-lg flex">
                {basket.length > 0 && (
                  <div className="">
                     <h2 className=" ">
                      Subtotal ({basket.length} items):
                      <span className="font-bold">
                           {sum}
                      </span>
                      </h2>
                        
                          <button 
                              onClick={createCheckoutForm}
                              type="submit"
                              role="link"
                              disabled={!session}
                              className={`button mt-2 ${
                                !session && 
                            ` from-gray-300 to-gray-500 border-gray-200 text-gray-100 cursor-not-allowed`
                            }`}
                            >
                            {!session ? 'Sign in to checkout' : 'Proceed to checkout' }
                          </button>
                   
                  </div>

                )}

            </div>
       </main>
    </div>
  )
}
```

let me know if there is another way I should format the code to make it easier to read!

Comment: Please use the title to convey your *technical* problem.

Comment: ok ill edit that now

Comment: I think `stripe.checkout.session.create` should be `stripe.checkout.sessions.create` add an s to session

Comment: that solved some of the problem! thanks

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you're passing `basket` (an array) to the backend as `items`. There's not really a reason to do that if all you're doing in that endpoint is creating a checkout session where you specify the sum total to charge the customer as `unit_amount`. You already have the sum total in a variable on the front-end: `sum`. Instead of passing the whole basket, just pass that `sum` from the front-end to your backend and create the checkout session with `unit_amount` as `sum` * 100.

However, it's recommended you pass a list of [Price](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create) id's to the [Checkout Session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price) instead of passing in a sum total from the front-end. This helps prevent data being manipulated from the front-end and allows you to keep track of exactly which items (Price objects) the customer is paying for in the backend.

Edit: If you really do want to go the route of specifying price_data inline instead of passing price id's (not recommended), then it does look like you'll need to also specify product_data, so that's probably why the tutorials you're following pass the whole basket to the backend. In that case, each item in the basket will need to be passed as a [line_item](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items) on the Checkout Session. So, you'll need to manipulate the items array in your backend to be in the same format as the line_items array that Checkout expects.